# Can the Stanford NLP library determine the case (nominative, accusative ...) of words?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm parsing some German text with the Stanford NLP library, and I want it to annotate every noun, pronoun (and article?) with the relevant case (nominative, accusative, ...).

Is there a class that does that?

I was excited for a moment to see a class called TrueCaseAnnotator, but it seemed like that actually had to do with uppercase/lowercase (although I never quite got it to work, so maybe I'm wrong about that?)

Comment: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml had a download link to a "full" version with taggers for multiple languages, including German. Not sure how detailed its tag set is but in order to fo POS tagging it has to do some amount of morphological analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there isn't. Sorry about that!